# Python group by and mean per column does not modify NaNs when adding a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan, mean

I have several data frames with same columns each for one month.  Each df has a set of Names mostly common ones but sometimes they are missing or NaNs, For example:

```
Name   Type  Value_m1
Sam    New   0.2
Alter  Old   0.3
Chita  New   0.11
```

Each month I merge the last 12 months (datasets) and make a time series data frame which looks like below:dfs_merged

```
Name   Type  Value_m1 Value_m2 ... Value_m12
Sam    New   0.2      0.1         0.4
Alter  Old   0.3     0.45        NaN
Chita  New   0.11    0.3         0.8    
XYZ    New   NaN     NaN        0.9
```

I would like to  group by "Type"  and get the mean of all columns (months).so

```
df_merged.groupby('Type').mean().T



Mean()         Old        New
Value_m1    0.300683    0.328031
Value_m2    0.313140    0.349417
.
.
.
Value_m12   0.339994    0.361857
```

However I noticed every time I add a df (a new month of data), my means for previous months also change. For example if I add month 13, the mean of month 1 also changes. I suspect it is due to NaN values.

```
 Mean()         Old       New
    Value_m1    0.343294    0.370553
    Value_m2    0.321687    0.38769
    .
    .
    .
    Value_m12   0.339988    0.361978
    Value_m13   0.339954    0.356666
```

Does any body have a suggestion how to do group by and mean for each value_m column ignoring NaNs only for that column? or other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. Please remember to include the [tag:pandas] tag if you are using pandas.

Comment: Pandas ignores `nan` in `df.groupby.mean`

Comment: So I read that, but then why do I get different values when I add a dataframe?